# How do i make update function in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

My project is a discussion forum using Django and here are my create and update functions. The method of `update_post` should provide update functionality but every time I try to update a post it adds a new post. How can I update a resource?

```
        @login_required
    def create_post(request):
        context = {}
        form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.is_valid():
                print("\n\n its valid")
                author = Author.objects.get(user=request.user)
                new_post = form.save(commit=False)
                new_post.user = author
                new_post.save()
                form.save_m2m()
                return redirect("home")
        context.update({
            "form": form,
            "title": "Create New Post"
        })
        return render(request, "create_post.html", context)
    

      @login_required
def update_post(request):
    context = {}
    author = Author.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = PostForm(request.POST , instance=author)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            print("\n\n its valid")
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
           # new_post.user = author
            new_post.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return redirect("home")
    context.update({
        "form": form,
        "title": "UpdatePost",
    })
    return render(request, "update_post.html", context)

In model total there are 4 classes Post , comment , reply and category and this is Post -

class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=400, unique=True, blank=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
content = HTMLField()
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
approved = models.BooleanField(default=True)
hit_count_generic = GenericRelation(HitCount, object_id_field='object_pk',
    related_query_name='hit_count_generic_relation'
)
tags = TaggableManager()
comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comment, blank=True)
closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
state = models.CharField(max_length=40, default="zero")
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_url(self):
    return reverse("detail", kwargs={
        "slug":self.slug
    })

@property
def num_comments(self):
    return self.comments.count()

@property
def last_reply(self):
    return self.comments.latest("date")
```

Comment: Hi :) Could you add your (I assume) Post and Author models as well as your PostForm? It helps figuring out what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

```py
form = PostForm(request.POST , instance=author)
```

`instance` feels like it should be passed an instance of `Post` instead of an instance of `Author`. I assume that `PostForm` is a pretty standard `ModelForm` with `model = Post` in the `Meta`.

Comment: posts=get_object_or_404(Post , id=id)   I did this but this is showing "update_post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id' " error.

Comment: You need to pass the `id` from the URL in some way, either as part of the POST data (`request.POST['id']`), the GET data (`request.GET['id']`) or specify the value in the URL path `path('update-post/<pk:id>/', update_post)`.